# What kind of animation would one use

Tags: android, animation, view, drawer

I am attempting a rather complicated animation in android. I want to be able to have a background image and have a sliding drawer come in from the left, *BUT* I don't want the drawer to come on over top of the the background image. Instead, I would like to squeeze the background so that you can see the drawer on the screen and the entire background image (though squeezed) at the same time.

I have looked into several animation but I can't come up with a combination that will do this.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Scale the background image with an anchor at the right side. Then translate the drawer from left (invisible area) to the right(visible area)

Comment: Thank you C.d for your timely response. Do you think you could be a little more specific? I'm still relatively new...

Also, I am going to have to do this same animation to not only a picture in the background but an entire layout. Will this method you're talking about work for that too?